# Node.js - Why does my callback get called 3 times for each request?

Tags: node.js

This is my VERY FIRST node app.  I'm literally just starting to piece through the API to see what it's all about.  I'm immediately confused by the following server code and my console output.  Can someone explain why my console.log happens 3 times on a browser refresh?

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  response.end("{blah: 1234}");
  console.log("Hello!");
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Output from a single refresh in the browser is:

```
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
```

What am I missing?

OSX 10.5, Node 0.4.3

Comment: A `tcpdump -s 0 -X` or equivalent would be nice, but I guess: HEAD, GET, GET /favicon.png

Comment: Also, great to work with the raw node http apis to learn (and then connect) but after that, checkout expressjs to create a real web app :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely your browser is actually sending these requests.

Change `console.log("Hello!")` to `console.log(request.url)` to see what the paths of those requests are.

With Chrome I get only two requests, one for `/` and one for `/favicon.ico`.

Comment: good call, I didn't consider the other requests being automatically made by the browser, favicon.ico etc...   What's really odd is that I get two requests for favicon with safari ??  Anyway besides the point, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can use a connect middleware to serve those favicons. http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-favicon.html

Comment: Use a command line HTTP agent like curl to do one specific request, ex : "curl http://localhost:3000/ -o -", this does one request and dumps the output to STDOUT

Comment: @brad -- don't keep us in suspense.  What was the third access?

Comment: @ Malvolio - I know it was a long time since you requested this, and I'm not @brad, but I'm seeing 3 requests also using Chrome- one to root / and two for /favicon.ico