# annoyance node.js calls httpserver callback function twice for one single page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

When loging the OnRequest function below (found in this tut http://www.nodebeginner.org/)

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request, response) {
  console.log("Request received.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

console.log("Server has started.");
```

log will print "Request received." twice each time I refresh the webpage only once : this is annoying since it means I can have side effects when making some other processing.

Why doesn't node.js mitigate this like other http servers ?

**My question is not WHY I know why, my question is HOW to detect that it is second time and avoid calling a heavy processing twice ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js - Why does my callback get called 3 times for each request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369506/node-js-why-does-my-callback-get-called-3-times-for-each-request)

Comment: Try `console.log(request.url)` and you'll see the reason.

Comment: My question is not WHY I know why, my question is HOW to detect that it is second time and avoid calling a heavy processing twice ?

Comment: I'm curious that you believe that other servers mitigate this.  That's interesting and false.  You could try only acknowledging requests to a specific URL path.

Comment: @user310291 Yeah I know you wanted me to spell out the answer for you without you needing to think for yourself. If you indeed had logged it you would have asked how to deal with requests for /favicon.ico, not some "second request". Just like every other server you have to decide what to do based on the requested url.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore favicon requests, just read the URL property of your request object, and handle the request. You could also send a `404 Not Found` if you preferred.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
  if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'});
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello, world!');
}).listen(80);
```

Also, your statement on how other web servers handle favicon requests is incorrect. Such as in Nginx, the request is handled like any other request is, which commonly results in many "file not found" errors in HTTP logs.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an additional request for favicon.ico.

Edit:

SO the solution in this case for example, would be to ignore requests for certain paths.

For example:

```
yourdomain.com/favicaon.ico
```

Would be met with no (404) response, whereas

```
yourdomain.com/some/infinitely/more/important/path
```

gets acknowledged with the more computationally expensive response.  But if somebody does indeed request this url twice, you need to acknowledge them twice.  Have you ever had google just inexplicably not load?  HTTP isn't perfect, network data gets lost.  What if they decided not to respond after you hit refresh?  NO MORE GOOGLE FOR YOU!

For example you could do something like this

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
    if (req.url.matches(/some\/important\/path/i') { 
        res.writeHead(200);//May need to add content-type, may not.
        res.write(someFunctionThatReturnsData());
        res.end();
    } else {//For favicon and other requests just write 404s
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write('This URL does nothing interesting');
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(80);
```